# Trying to return related nodes neo4jclient

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I am trying to find items that are related to a specific item (node 3).  I am receiving an error on the query.results statement.  I keep receiving "No parameterless constructor defined for this object".  Does anyone know what I am missing?

Code:

```
Dim query As Cypher.CypherFluentQuery(Of Neo4jClient.NodeReference(Of TestGraph2.Item))
query = client.Cypher.Start("n", 3).Match("n-[r]->()<-[r2]-other").Return(Of NodeReference(Of Item))("other")
Dim x As IEnumerable(Of System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Neo4jClient.NodeReference(Of TestGraph2.Item))())
x = query.Results.ToList
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return a `Node<T>` instead of `NodeReference<T>`:

```
Dim query As Cypher.CypherFluentQuery(Of Neo4jClient.Node(Of TestGraph2.Item))
query = client.Cypher.Start("n", 3).Match("n-[r]->()<-[r2]-other").Return(Of Node(Of Item))("other")
Dim x As IEnumerable(Of System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Neo4jClient.Node(Of TestGraph2.Item))())
x = query.Results.ToList
```

The ability to just use `NodeReference` instead of `Node` is in [issue 35](https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/issue/35/cypher-should-be-able-to-flatten-nodes-to), however not implemented yet.

---

PS: My VB.NET is rather out of date, but the code you've supplied looks extremely verbose.

Here's the C# equivalent:

```
var query = client.Cypher
    .Start(new { n = 3 })
    .Match("n-[r]->()<-[r2]-other")
    .Return<Node<Item>>("other")
var x = query.Results.ToList()
```

I would expect/hope/pray that your VB.NET code could be made more succinct.

Comment: Thank you. The only other thing I had to change was:  Dim x As List(Of Neo4jClient.Node(Of TestGraph2.Item))